# Best architecture for an emergency alert system

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database-design, architecture

I'm developing a software system which receives information (which is saved to a database) and when any information is received (new insert in a specific table) an alert should be seen in the screen in the information center, so proper action can be taken.

I'm writing an application with ASPNET MVC, SQL Server 2008 Express, SQL Agent free for that version of SQL Server, Entity Framework 4, Visual Studio 2010, etc.

Right now, I've set the database and a SQL job that monitors the table each minute, if there is a new records an email is sent to same addresses. My problem is...What then? Which would be the best architecture to follow?
A couple of option I thought about are:

1) In the job connect to a web service and that web service an the web service can open a popup
2) The web page could be pooling the database table to know if there are new records

Is there any way to make push to the web page instead of the page pooling the database server?

I know maybe windows application would fit better here, but right now I must stick with ASPNET MVC as I already started and don't want to create another application.
Thanks! Daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to make push to the web page instead of the page pooling the database server?

HTML5 [WebSockets](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/). Draft, pretty new, specification is still subject to change, to all browsers implement it. You will need a [WebSocket Server](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/c_sharp_web_socket_server.aspx). If you go that route make sure you read [this guy's blog](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/). He is behind [Laharsub](http://laharsub.codeplex.com/) which is a must try server.

Comment: Darin, thanks for your quick response.
The problem with HTML 5 is that it won't be release at least for 2 more years from what I've read, that gives a lot of possibilities to change it and give me headaches in the future...

Comment: html5 is already supported by most browsers to various degrees, although the websockets part is (i think) only supported by chrome so far

Comment: There are several javascript websocket frameworks which are backwards compatible with the help of a flash component. Google

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you are able to use Silverlight to push data down to the client. Here is [a pretty good overview](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2008/04/10/pushing-data-to-a-silverlight-client-with-sockets-part-i.aspx) that I read a while back. HTML5 might be a better way to go. But with such limited support it's almost not worth it at this point. Granted the Silverlight application might be out of reach to, but it's still a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you look into (complex) event processing, or stream processing -- at least to get the feeling for architecture of these systems.

The idea is to capture a stream of events **before** they reach database, route them (process) within the event processor and put them in the DB from there -- treating the DB as only one of event destinations (subscribers).

Take a look at **[Streambase](http://www.streambase.com/)**, **[ruleCore](http://rulecore.com/component/option,com_frontpage/Itemid,1/)**, and **[many others](http://www.complexevents.com/2005/04/08/progress-software/)**.

These were all developed for the type of scenario you described.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see the problem from the other angle. Develop a web client that reads the database every minute and compare to last pull ...

Comment: I'm not keen on that, as I might be connection to the database too much for nothing, I mean, in the case that there are no new events for a long period.